# Cancelling terms in tensor notation

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

Suppose I have some tensorial equation like,

$$ \partial^r K^{\mu \nu} p_{\mu} p_{\nu} p_r = - \partial^{\theta} K^{\mu \nu} p_{\mu} p_{\nu} p_{\theta}$$

Now if this were a simple algebraic equation we could cancel the $p_{\mu} p_{\nu}$ terms. However, **I am confused** whether this is a valid operation in tensorial notation, given that we are considering summations over indices.

Can anyone help me understand when canceling terms like this is (not) valid?

Thanks

Comment: does $\sum_{i}a_ib_i=\sum_{i}a_ic_i$ imply $b_i=c_i$?

Comment: No, you can't cancel $p_\mu p_\nu$. To see this, note that $X^{\mu\nu} p_\mu p_\nu = 0$ whenever $X$ is antisymmetric. So if you naively canceled, you would say that $X$ would have to be zero. What you can say is that the symmetric parts of the two tensors (under $\mu \nu$ symmetrization) are equal.

Comment: @knzhou that should be an answer...

Comment: @knzhou could you expand on your answer, particularly re the symmetric parts being equal?

Comment: However the equation is not a tensorial one, as it shows a partial derivative.